# I'm getting this Tomcat error

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

[image: Error image]

```
 SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@269f4bad]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@269f4bad]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4893)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:751)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:761)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:407)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:309)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:768)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:397)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:112)
        ... 34 more

    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
        ... 13 more

    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Jan 04, 2018 5:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/E:/Apache/apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/lib/catalina.jar) to field java.lang.Thread.threadLocals
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Well, I tried restarting the server, deleting the server and even reinstalling the server. I even reinstalled the whole TomCat, but it's still not working. I even removed the maven project and wrote it again. Still showing me the same error.
Anyone know where the root of this error is? 
I'm using Eclipse Oxygen 2.0 and Tomcat 9.0.1 and JDK 9.
I'm running out of options to do and I just started learning maven like one month ago.

Comment: You need to provide the 'Details' from the screenshot and/or Console.

Comment: Look in the logfile ....

Comment: Post both the relevant code as well as the problem description / stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace in the logfile indicates that you have a corrupted EAR, WAR, JAR or ZIP file.  (EAR, WAR and JAR files are really just ZIP files with special naming structures ...)

This is most likely a problem with your webapp (e.g. a with the way you built or deployed it) rather than with Tomcat.